# Find files with certain file extensions c++

Tags: c++, regex, file-find

I can find .jpg files
But how can I find .jpg, .bmp, .png .... files?

Mask

```
LPWSTR mask = stoL(path + "*.(jpg)");
```

Handler initialization

```
HANDLE hf = FindFirstFile(mask, &FindFileData);
```

String to LPWSTR

```
LPWSTR stoL(string s) {
    return CA2T(s.c_str());
}
```

Comment: can you overwrite this, please

(path + "*.(jpg)")

Comment: `path + "\.(jpg|png|bmp)$"`

Comment: but does `+` acts as concatenation in C++?

Comment: acts http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator+/

Comment: try this one with `\\.(jpg|png|bmp)$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find multiple extensions, you have two choices: you can either search separately for each extension you care about, or you can do one search for all files, then see if each file fits one of the extensions you care about.

Something like `*.(jpg|png|bmp)` just isn't going to work--`FindFirstFile` and `FindNextFile` don't recognize `(`, `|` or `)`, so given this pattern, it'll be searching for a single extension--i.e., all files that literally have the characters `(jpg|png|bmp)` as their extension (which will normally fail, of course).